# Load and Play Video from V4L2 in Android like Live TV

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, v4l2

I have a requirement that i have to load and Play the Video from V4L2 in Android.
I am an Android application developer and i know how to stream and play a video from URL. But, here the case is completely different. I have to create an application for Android TV (CX23102 Usb based driver).
Anyone please let me know where to start. Is my Java knowledge is enough or JNI is required?